# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n + 3^n)\sin(n)}{2^n + n^2\cdot3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Proving the convergence of a series by Weierstrass M-test.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2^n + 3^n)\sin(n)}{2^n + n^2\cdot3^n}.$$

$$\frac{(2^n + 3^n)\sin(n)}{2^n + n^2\cdot3^n} \leq \frac{2^n + 3^n}{2^n + n^2 \cdot 3^n} = \frac{1 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{1 + n^2 \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}.$$
Further I got stuck how to evaluate and get convergence.

Comment: You have to estimate the absolute value of the $n$th term, i.e., put absolute values around the sine.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{(2^{n}+3^{n})\sin n}{2^{n}+n^{2}3^{n}}\right|\leq\dfrac{2^{n}+3^{n}}{2^{n}+n^{2}3^{n}}\leq\dfrac{3^{n}+3^{n}}{n^{2}3^{n}}=\dfrac{2}{n^{2}},
\end{align*}
now $\sum n^{-2}<\infty$.